# return IDictionary<string, ICollection<ValueSet>>

Tags: c#, collections

I'm trying to return interface `IDictionary` (with string key and List values) like:

```
IDictionary<string, ICollection<ValueSet>> method( ...) {

}
```

From inside of the method I create the Dictionary object:

```
var dic = new Dictionary <string, List <ValueSet> >();
```

Everything works well, but I can't return the `dic` object here. I cannot implicitly convert.

How can I make this thing work?

```
public IDictionary < string, ICollection < ValueSet > > GetValueSets(ICollection < string > contentSetGuids)

{
    var dic = new Dictionary < string, List < ValueSet > > ();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ValueSet.ValueSetQueryText);
        sb.Append(" where contentsetguid ");
        sb.Append(CreateInClause(contentSetGuids));

        command.CommandText = sb.ToString();

        dic = GetObjects(command).GroupBy(vs => vs.ContentSetGuid).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());

    }

    return dic;
}
```

Error:
Error   46  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: C# ........................

Comment: Can you update your question to have the full method shown, along with the full error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast a `IDictionary<String, List<ValueSet>>` to a `IDictionary<String, ICollection<ValueSet>>` because `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not [*covariant*](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx?Redirected=true). For example, the `IEnumerable<T>` interface *is* covariant, so you could cast `IEnumerable<List<ValueSet>>` to `IEnumerable<ICollection<ValueSet>>` if you wanted.

However, you can solve your problem somewhat by creating a dictionary of the correct type in your method. For example:

```
public IDictionary<string, ICollection<ValueSet>> GetValueSets(
    ICollection<ValueSet> contentSetGuids)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<ValueSet>>();   // <--

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        // ...
        dic = GetObjects(command)
              .GroupBy(vs => vs.ContentSetGuid)
              .ToDictionary(
                  grp => grp.Key,
                  grp => (ICollection<ValueSet>)grp.ToList());   // <--
    }

    return dic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing the interface to somewhat more flexible:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ValueSet>> GetValueSets(
    IEnumerable<ValueSet> contentSetGuids)

{
    // ....
    return GetObjects(command)
        .GroupBy(vs => vs.ContentSetGuid)
        .Select(new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ValueSet>>(grp.Key, grp.ToArray())
}
```

Let the caller create a dictionary, it it requires one.

*normally* I would pass the string (the key) as argument and return only one element at once. But in the method, you get the whole data at once, so this doesn't make much sense.