# How do I force ToDictionary() to match the return type of the function I'm returning its value from?

Tags: c#

Given the following method,

```cs
private static IDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<string>> GetDict()
{
    var groups = new List<List<string>>()
    {
        new() { "one", "two", "three" },
        new() { "four", "five", "six" }
    };

    return groups.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x.Skip(1).ToList().AsReadOnly());
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> [CS0266] Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't understand why this isn't working. `Dictionary` should be implicitly upcast to `IDictionary` and the internal types match exactly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That said, what you can do is `return groups.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => (IReadOnlyCollection<string>)x.Skip(1).ToList().AsReadOnly());`

Comment: Also, more closely related though for the same reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967015/return-idictionarystring-icollectionvalueset

Comment: @Ray strong agree.  I've edited the dup list and moved that one to the top.

Comment: @KirkWoll Blame me, I originally suggested that other question :o) I didn't know one could edit the dupe list.

Comment: @Ray ha, no worries.  I _think_ you should be able to edit close reasons, but not sure what rep-level activates that, honestly.